# live chat rails private_pub

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Не получается настроить публикацию комментариев в чат с помощью гема private_pub

Сами комментарии не публикуются сразу при нажатии отправить, нужно перезагружать страницу, не могу понять в чем проблема, появилась она после того как переключил в контроллере на respond_to ... format.js

Мой контроллер - **messages_controller.rb**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!


    def create
        @chat = Chat.find(params[:chat_id])
        @message = Message.create(params[:message].permit(:content))
        @message.user_id = current_user.id
        @message.chat_id = @chat.id

        respond_to do |format|
            if @message.save
                format.js do
                    PrivatePub.publish_to "/chats/#{@chat.id}/messages", message: @message.to_json
                #redirect_to chat_path(@chat), notice: "Комментарий добавлен успешно"
                    render nothing: true
                end
                #format.html {redirect_to chat_path(@chat), notice: "Комментарий добавлен успешно"}
            else
                format.js do
                    PrivatePub.publish_to "/chats/#{@chat.id}/messages", errors: @messages.errors.full_messages
                    render nothing: true
                    #render 'new'
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Moй **chats/show.html.erb**

```
<div id="comments" data-chat-id="<%= @chat.id %>" >
  <% @messages.each do |message| %>
    <div class="comment">
      <div id="avatar">
        <%= link_to gravatar_for(message.user, size: 70) %>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <h5 class="username">User Name: <%= message.user.name %></h5>
        <p class=content><%= message.content %></p>
        <span class="quiet"><small>created: <%= time_ago_in_words(message.created_at) %> ago</small></span>
      </div>
    </div>

  <% end %>
</div>

<%= render "messages/form" %>

<%= subscribe_to "/chats/#{@chat.id}/messages" %>
```

В **aplication.js** добавил

```
//= require private_pub
```

Вот мой **messages.coffee**

```
$ ->
  chatId = $('#comments').data('chatId');
  chanel = '/chats/' + chatId + '/messages'
  PrivatePub.subscribe chanel, (data, chanel) ->
    console.log(data)
    message = $.parseJSON(data['message'])
    $('#comments').append(message.content)
    $('.new_message #message_content').val('');
```

Вот мой **messages/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for [@chat, @chat.messages.build], remote: true, data: {type: :json} do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :content, "Reply to thread" %><br />
      <%= f.text_area :content %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Create", class: "button" %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

Но комментарии так и не публикуются сразу и тем более не работает private_pub

Вот весь код на github

https://github.com/darelvc/chat_app

Прошу подсказать в чем именно проблема.

Comment: А сервер websocket запущен?

Comment: Запускал командой

rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production

Comment: А что в консоли хрома выдает при загрузке страниы? А при отправке камента?

Comment: Можно проверить сейчас работу приложения тут - https://chat-app-darelvc.c9users.io/chats/1

Comment: Если смотреть код то субскрайб отображается корректно

<%= subscribe_to "/chats/#{@chat.id}/messages" %>

/chats/1/messages

Comment: У вас скрипт faye.js не подгружается отсюда - 'http://localhost:9292/faye.js'

Comment: Странно, может это c9.io так подгружает... Сейчас из дому попробую на локальной машине развернуть

Вот выложил тот же проект на heroku - https://darelvc-chat.herokuapp.com/chats/1 то там что-то тоже не загружает

Comment: Большущее тебе спасибо, на локалке все взлетело, правда стили подгружаются лишь после обновления страницы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была связана с протоколом https и спецификой сервиса с9.io

На локальном компьютере все заработало идеально.

Для деплоя проекта на heroku.com я использовал файл **Procfile**

```
web: bundle exec rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -p $PORT -E production
```